# Multiple nodes with the same receiving and transmitting address

Tags: nrf24l01+

I want to make a network with arduinos and nrf24l01 chips. The network will be like this:

- 1 master arduino
- multiple (no specific number) slave nodes

I want all nodes to have the same receiving and the same transmitting address and the master arduino to understand which one send the message from the message itself.
For example:

**Master:** 
Receiving: 0xABCDABCD71
Transmitting: 0xABCDABCD01

**Slave 1**
Receiving: 0xABCDABCD01
Transmitting: 0xABCDABCD71

**Slave 2**
Receiving: 0xABCDABCD01
Transmitting: 0xABCDABCD71

**Slave 3**
Receiving: 0xABCDABCD01
Transmitting: 0xABCDABCD71

**Slave 4**
Receiving: 0xABCDABCD01
Transmitting: 0xABCDABCD71

When master send a message, all nodes will receive it.
What I want to ask is :

- Is that possible?
- Will there be any problems?
- Is there any other way so I can add more nodes in the future without changing the code?

Comment: That will work. The only possible problem would be collisions, if the nodes send a lot of data (having different re-transmit intervals _might_ help here).

Comment: Generally, having same RX address on all slave nodes is a bad idea except when the slaves are receive only.  If you want to receive data from a specific node, then they should have different addresses, use ACK_PAYLOAD and you poll each one in turn.

Comment: Can we do it for only multiple slaves to single data receiver?
I want to get 13 IMUs( gy9250) data on single nrf24lo1 receiver is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as well as comment #1 the other thing will be the ack packets that the slaves will send back to the master to confirm message recieved. with all slaves sending back a ack at about the same time there will be no way for master to tell which ack is from which client, and thus who needs a retransmit. a way around this is to turn off ack for the clients and make the master transmit max times regardless. there is a rf24 fork that has broadcast mode, the makes it more easy to specify not to wait for ack before retransmitting

Comment: Using [this](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24) as a base library and [this](http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24Network/) as an simplifying overlay (there's actually RF24Mesh too) will make this possible very easily.